# Weird italic "g" in Roboto font

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

To me, the font looks weird in italic, the "g" looks more like a "ç":

[image: Macento]

Not a big issue, but it still disturbs the reading flow, maybe you could consider a different type for italics.

Comment: What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 7, looks the same in Chrome and Firefox there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for sharing this issue. I could reproduce the issue on Windows 8.1 in Chrome and Firefox. After swapping out a different set of font files, it appears the issue was with the previous font files. I wouldn't say they were corrupted, but they had some odd artifacts within them.

The files have been updated and should work correctly now.

[image: Look Mom! My g's are displaying correctly!]

^^^ This screenshot was taken in Windows 8.1 Chrome.

Comment: *ggg* - looks good now, thanks!